# Apache Spark - Few straggler tasks slowing down a stage and the job

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, orc

I have a spark job which reads, deduplicates and joins datasets stored in S3. The stored data is in ORC format and zlib compressed. In the first stage(the reading and deduplicating part), a small number of straggler tasks take up a great amount of time to complete. I analysed the metrics and found the following:

1. The tasks are processing nearly the same amount of data.
2. Shuffle writes for the tasks are nearly the same.
3. GC duration for each task is negligible.

Please find some screenshots for reference. One of the screenshots shows the metrics. The other depicts the time taken (30 mins / 4.1 mins) for two tasks with barely any difference in shuffle writes(9.2 mb/10.3 mb) or data skew(6.4M/7.2M) and without any considerable GC lag(5s/1s).

I am lost here, no idea what could be causing this to happen. Any help would be appreciated.

Best Regards

Note: IPs have been removed from the fifth column in the second image.
[image]
[image]

Comment: check with the support team, as this sounds like it is a problem with the cluster itself.

Also, Possibly an imbalance in your data key distribution. Take a look at the size of each partition and also make sure that if you're joining, the join key doesn't have imbalanaces. You can check that latter one by grouping by the join key and counting, order descending